# How to set a default initialization cookie in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I was wondering if anyone can shed some light on cookie management. More precisely I would like to know how I could set up an initial cookie/s when a user start a session in a website.

Currently the `ASP.NET_SessionId cookie` is located on user computers when they navigate to the domain. I would like to set up an additional cookie with details of `languageid` and `countryid` with default parameters the first time the user navigate to the site.

Do anyone knows if there is any technique to do this, such as through web.config set up or placing cookie details using layout.cshtml like

```
Response.Cookies["language"].Value = "1";

Response.Cookies["country"].Value= "7";
```

or similar?, any option will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this in an action filter:

```
public class LocalizationAwareAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var httpContext = filterContext.HttpContext.Current;

        if (!httpContext.Cookies.Keys.Contains("language"))
        {
            httpContext.Response.AppendCookie(new HttpCookie("language", 1));
        }
        if (!httpContext.Cookies.Keys.Contains("country"))
        {
            httpContext.Response.AppendCookie(new HttpCookie("country", 7));
        }
    }
}
```

The filter can be applied globally, so you don't have to worry about remembering it on each action method or controller.

Comment: Hit Tomas, I will test it in my app and come back with details. thank you.

Comment: This seems like the best way to do it! And for the `if (incoming request doesn't already has the cookie)`, you just check `filterContext.HttpRequest.Current.Cookies`, right? @Tomas, quick question: shouldn't you be adding the cookies to the httpresponse, not request?

Comment: @Maxim: True! I just took a quick code example from a google search without reflecting over all the details :P I'll update accordingly. And yes, the check should be performed as you suggest.

Comment: I implemented but var httpContext = filterContext.HttpRequest.Current; is not available as an option. intellisense marks httprequest as not an option... weird

Comment: @sebastian_h: I haven't tried this out in VS yet, but maybe something like `filterContext.HttpContext`?

Comment: @Tomas one more question! How would you apply such a filter globally? I've never figured out how to do that, except by creating an HttpModule.

Comment: @sebastian_h: Sorry, that was a typo of mine. It should be `filterContext.HttpContext`.

Comment: @Maxim: It requires MVC3, but it's really simple. You can read up on it [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/08/15/asp-net-mvc-3-global-action-filters.aspx), [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/27/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx) and [here](http://www.google.se/search?q=asp.net+mvc+3+global+action+filter)

Answer (score 3):

I haven't worked much with cookies in ASP.NET MVC, but the way I'd do it would be to have a little block of code in Global.asax or a separate base controller that gets executed on every request. This code would check the HttpContext for the existence of such a cookie, and if it didn't exist, it would create one. I'll work up a code sample and will update this answer soon.

Comment: thank you @maxim_zaslavsky . I read all msdn details but I cant find any example of it. thanks